# Does data duplication in microservice architecture lead to code duplication?

Tags: architecture, microservices, code-duplication

For example, we have an application with microservice architecture. The services communicate with each other using an event bus as follows:

1. TeamService subscribes to `UserCreated` event
2. UserService publishes the `UserCreated` event
3. TeamService stores the user from the `UserCreated` event to its own database

So, we duplicate data in some services. And that's okay in microservices architecture. But what about the code that processes this data?  For example, the user might have `isPublic` field. If the `isPublic` field is false, the user's profile information is visible only to the user himself and to a user with administrator rights.

Thus, UserService and TeamService must have the same code to handle this logic. Or is there another way to handle the `isPublic` field without code duplication?

Comment: What you ended up doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a library which contains the common code, and add it as a dependency in both `UserService` and `TeamService`

Comment: A library which contains the common business logic is hard to maintain. Business logic changes frequently, so you often need to republish the library and redeploy all the affected services.

Comment: That's true, but you want to solve code duplication. If you don't want to create a new library, you can create a `common` module in the same project, and put the common logic there

Comment: As far as I understand, I still need to redeploy every service that uses this module

Answer (score 0):

In microservice architecture, data may be replicate in multiple services for e.g. User Service and Team Service but only one service own and serve the data. For e.g., user profile data is owned by User service and it should be served by user service only.

So, if any UI or other service want to show profile service then it ask the same to User service and User service may reject (access denied) if the profile is not public.

Comment: Several services can serve the same data. For example a search service can serve data from other services.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. In several scenario, a service serve the data own by another service. But in your scenario, we should avoid this to simplify the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to disallow other services from handling user-related logic directly. Instead, services that wish to enact such logic should call the user service to perform the desired logic for them. Depending on your requirements and the particular services in place, the calls can also be asynchronous to conform to an event-driven architecture.